# issue with CheckBoxPreference in preferenceActivity

Tags: android

I want to implement a preference activity.

i have two `CheckBoxPreference`:

```
CheckBoxPreference a ( default value false)
CheckBoxPreference b( default value false )
```

I want it so that if user checks `preference a`  he **can not** check `preference b,` and if for first check preference b he cant check the a.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope these links can useful to you and you can get some idea from here...:)

```
you can try with **android:disableDependentsState="false"** or you can [Check here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/CheckBoxPreference.html) and [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#disableDependentsState)
```